# Processing TSV file into NSArray using CHCSVParser

Tags: objective-c, csv

I have a TSV file stored in Documents in an iOS 7 application, and I'm trying to process the file using CHCSVParser into an `NSArray` (of `NSArray` objects).

The code I'm currently trying to use is this:

```
NSArray *fields = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFile options:CHCSVParserOptionsRecognizesBackslashesAsEscapes];
```

This works great if I convert the file to CSV, rather than TSV before hand, although this wouldn't be an option in production.

I know CHCSVParser has the ability to also parse TSV files, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in a similar way to above, being able to specify the delimiter. Am I looking in the wrong place for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that issue myself and, for the love of me, I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

So in the end I modified the code a bit (Below is a bit out the top of my head, mind you).

Added a new method `arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:options:delimiter:`

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath options:(CHCSVParserOptions)options delimiter:(unichar)delimiter {
    NSParameterAssert(csvFilePath);
    _CHCSVAggregator *aggregator = [[_CHCSVAggregator alloc] init];
    CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFilePath delimiter:delimiter];
    [parser setDelegate:aggregator];

    [parser setRecognizesBackslashesAsEscapes:!!(options & CHCSVParserOptionsRecognizesBackslashesAsEscapes)];
    [parser setSanitizesFields:!!(options & CHCSVParserOptionsSanitizesFields)];
    [parser setRecognizesComments:!!(options & CHCSVParserOptionsRecognizesComments)];
    [parser setStripsLeadingAndTrailingWhitespace:!!(options & CHCSVParserOptionsStripsLeadingAndTrailingWhitespace)];

    [parser parse];
    CHCSV_RELEASE(parser);

    NSArray *final = CHCSV_AUTORELEASE(CHCSV_RETAIN([aggregator lines]));
    CHCSV_RELEASE(aggregator);

    return final;
}
```

Added another new method `initWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFilePath:delimiter:`

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath delimiter:(unichar)delimiter {
    NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:csvFilePath];
    NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
    return [self initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:&encoding delimiter:delimiter];
}
```

So now I specify the delimiter every time I wish like so:

```
[arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:file options:options delimiter:'\t'];
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much! If I were you, I'd look at sending a pull request to the CHCSVParser project on GitHub to fix this [issue](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser/issues/55).

Comment: Glad to help :) I'm planning in fact to do so, I have a couple other improvements in line as well.

Comment: Can you add some more explanation about the code. Specially about the options.